# Lambda Python Dynamodb order by not working on specific field

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am using Lambda Python and get record from DynamodDB using query KeyConditionExpression.
I want order by specific field (createdAt (timestamp)) but not working it.
Here is my code:

```
import json
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key

def lambda_handler(event, context):    
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table('mytable')
    resp = table.query(
         IndexName='empid-template_for-index',
         KeyConditionExpression=
             Key('template_for').eq('mytemplate') & Key('empid').eq('myempid'),
         Limit=10,
         ScanIndexForward=False,
     )
     print(resp)
```

Can you please help me, how I can get top 10 record in descending order of field createdAt?

Comment: Can you share the partition key and sort key of your table?

Comment: @stijndepestel partition key for table is "query_id" and sort key not defined. For above query created index which partition key is "empid" and sort key is "template_for" I want same Key Condition but want to order by using created field.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order the results of a DynamoDB query, you'll always need to have this attribute as a sort key. This can be either the sort key of the index of the table, a global secondary index or a local secondary index, but it is not possible to retrieve the results ordered any other way.

The other possibility for ordering on another attribute is to order them client-side which has the obvious downsides of having to load all the data in memory and executing a sorting algorithm on the entire data set. This is obviously not feasible for large datasets and might increase the amount of data that you need to retrieve.

From [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html):

> Query results are always sorted by the sort key value. If the data type of the sort key is Number, the results are returned in numeric order. Otherwise, the results are returned in order of UTF-8 bytes. By default, the sort order is ascending. To reverse the order, set the ScanIndexForward parameter to false.